# HighCharts Rendering Issue In Chrome

Tags: highcharts

I have developed a website that makes heavy use of HighCharts. It has been working perfectly for almost a year, but a month or two ago I have noticed a rendering issue in Chrome.

The canvases where the graphs are to be drawn remain blank and fractions of the graph pop up on mouse over. This does not happen in Firefox, and it did not happen in Chrome until a month or two back. I have not made any changes to the source code at all and all JavaScript libraries that I use have a local copy.

I have tried updating the HighCharts version but the problem did not go away. It seems the issue only happens in pages where I draw more than one graph.

Here is an example: http://dmir.inesc-id.pt/popstar-dev/sentimento.php?lang=EN

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just tested with `Chrome 34.0.1847.137 m` and `Chrome 35.0.1916.114 m` - both works fine.

Comment: I'll try to determine the exact versions that seem to have an issue. Thanks, Pawel.

Answer (score 4):

add this in your css to force hardware acceleration where your calling the chart in your html

-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

Is a chrome ver 37 issue.

"Layer squashing Issues"

Comment: could you tell where exactly in the css add that line? I tried in the container div, in the inner divs, and outter divs, nothing worked. thanks

Comment: works for me! add this to the SVG tag. Tested on Chrome 37.0.2062.124m